# Whats wrong with this argument that $\operatorname{Spec}(\prod A_i) = \bigsqcup\operatorname{Spec}(A_i)$ infinite product.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification, limits-colimits

We have the spec functor $\text{CRng}^\text{op} \rightarrow \text{Aff}$.$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$
Then  $$\Hom _{\text{Aff}}(\Spec(\lim A_i), \Spec B) = \Hom_{\text{CRng}} (B, \lim A_i) $$
$$ = \lim \Hom_{\text{CRng}} (B,A_i) = \lim\Hom_{\text{Aff}}(\Spec A_i, \Spec B) 
$$
$$ =  \Hom_{\text{Aff}}(\text{colim} \Spec(A_i), \Spec B) $$

This means $\Spec(\lim A_i)$ and $\text{colim} \Spec(A_i)$ both represent the same object.

But this clearly does not make sense when the colimit is infinite. What went wrong?

Comment: In fact, nothing. Rather, you have shown that infinite coproducts in the category of affine schemes are different from in the category of schemes.

Comment: Spec is very ambiguous notation! It is used to name at least *four* different functors, with four different target categories, and these functors don’t have the same behaviors with respect to limits and colimits.

Comment: ah.. I see, thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't make sense of what you write : a contravariant  representable functor must have as codomain the category of sets, not the category of affine schemes (Grothendieck, EGA Chapter 0, (1.1.8), page 22, Springer New Edition ).

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg $\textbf{Aff}$ is equivalent to $\textbf{CRing}^\textrm{op}$ and $\textbf{CRing}$ has infinite products, therefore $\textbf{Aff}$ has infinite coproducts. They are not preserved by the inclusion $\textbf{Aff} \to \textbf{Sch}$.

Comment: Dear @Zhen Lin: you are right of course. But do you consider, contrary to Dieudonné-Grothendieck, that functors with codomain different from the category of sets (like in the OP's question  where the target is *Aff*) ) can be representable? In case your answer is yes, what does "representable" mean?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg If you're referring to the use of "represent" in the original post, I suspect Bryan just meant that these two *notations* represent isomorphic objects, not anything about representability of functors *per se*.

Comment: @Kevin Arlin: Ah yes, thanks for your hypothesis: that's a possible interpretation, but I wouldn't recommend that usage of "represent the same object" .

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes, I agree it should be avoided.

Comment: Dear @Kevin Arlin : I'm  glad that we are on the same wavelength!

Comment: But does this prove the ismorphism if the index set $I$ is finite (i.e. finite coproducts as schemes or as affine schemes are the same)? As I think one can show the coproduct is an affine scheme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equality $\operatorname{Spec}(\prod A_i) = \bigsqcup\operatorname{Spec}(A_i)$  **is always false in the category of schemes** if the set of indices $i$ is infinite and all the $A_i$ are $\neq 0$.
Indeed $\operatorname{Spec}(\prod A_i)$ is quasi-compact (like any  $\operatorname{Spec})$, whereas $\bigsqcup\operatorname{Spec}(A_i)$ is never quasi-compact.

**NB** As quite judiciously commented by @Zhen Lin, the coproduct of affine schemes is different in the category of schemes from the coproduct in the category of affine schemes (which I have never seen used in algebraic geometry).

Answer (score 0):

The very last step is wrong.

The thing is that given a scheme $X$, the functor $B \longmapsto \mathrm{Hom}(X,\mathrm{Spec}\,B)$ does not characterize $X$. Indeed, that functor depends only on the ring of global sections of $X$ (so, for instance, it is the same for the spectrum of a field and $\mathbb{P}^1$ of the same field).

So instead of showing equality for your two schemes, you just proved they had the same global sections – something you could have done anyway.

Comment: But *au contraire*, your functor **does** characterize $X$: remember that in this question only affine schemes are allowed (you cannot represent a functor by an object not in the domain category !).

Comment: That’s a very good point. I didn’t notice the category indeed.